# How to get GettyImages API-KEY?

Tags: c#

I want searching an image from iStock with GettyImage(C#), I want to enter the first search result image and get the tag, maker, title of that image, etc. But I don't know how to get the Api-Key. How do I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought it would be easy but it seems like it's not. There is no way to test the api without joining as an affiliate first.

First of all [gettyimages get-started-now](https://affiliates.gettyimages.com/get-started-now/) will set you on your course.

As mentioned:

> Join our affiliate platform, Impact.

Once inside, you can get your api key from the platform. Check the [documentation here](https://affiliates.gettyimages.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/10/partner-success-starter-pack.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Why takes so long?(4days).
Why does the review take a long time?

Comment: I don't have "okay" or "no" email.